Does such a concave function exist?
I'm trying to do the following problem:

Let $g(x):\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be concave and monotonically increasing, $g(0)=0$, and non-affine/linear. Then, impose the condition $$g(x+y) \le a \cdot g(x) + b \cdot g(y), $$ where $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, $a \in (0,1]$, $b>0$ independent of $a$. Does such a function (along with $a,b$ specific to the function) exist?

I think when the domain is restricted to the non-negative reals, $x\mapsto x^\alpha$ for $\alpha \in (0,1)$ would work. But I don't know how to handle the general domain case. Would anybody have any ideas or solutions to this? I'd be happy to know what happens if we relax the monotonically increasing assumption to just monotonic, if progress is difficult.
